# Contador con For e IF JAVA

Tags: java

Dado como datos N números enteros, obtenga el número de ceros ingresados en todo conjunto de números. Pero no me esta contando los ceros. Alguna sugerencia?
Llevo lo siguiente de codigo:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Inciso11F
    //Inicio programa
      {
    public static void main (String [] args)
      {
    //Inicio metodos
       Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);    
       int n=0,c=0,s=0,contador=0; 
    //Declaracion de variables
  //Entrada
System.out.println ("Bienvenido al sumador de 0´s");
  //Proceso
System.out.println ("Ingresa la cantidad de datos a calcular");
  s=entrada.nextInt();
for (c=1;c<=s;c++) {    
 System.out.println ("Ingresa el numero"+c);
 n=entrada.nextInt();
}
if (n<=0)
  contador++;
 System.out.println ("El total de 0´s es"+contador);
entrada.close();
}// Fin del metodo
}// Fin-clase
```

Comment: mira como preguntar en el recorrido

Answer (score 2):

Empecemos por partes:

Tu tienes declarado como int, n, c, s, contador (`int n = 0,c = 0,s = 0,contador = 0;`.

Luego, haces el for para pedir los números por consola

```
for(c = 1;c <= s;c++) {
      System.out.println("Ingresa el numero" + c);
      n = entrada.nextInt();
}
```

Donde, como puedes ver, a n que es de tipo integer, en cada iteración, se le cambia el valor, por lo que, da igual lo que le pase en la primera iteración, que lo único que va a tener como valor es el último entero que se le pase por consola.

Es ahí donde reside el error. Por lo que, puedes hacer dos cosas:
La primera es cambiar el valor de `n` de int a List y comprobar el valor sobre la lista así:

```
// Declaramos las variables
    List<Integer> n = new ArrayList<>();
    int c = 0,s = 0,contador = 0;

// Modificamos el bucle for ya que hemos cambiado el valor de n a lista de Integer
for(c = 1;c <= s;c++) {
      System.out.println("Ingresa el numero" + c);
      n.add(entrada.nextInt());
}
// Y luego, hacemos otro for para recorrer la lista de Integer
for(Integer i:n) {
      if(i <= 0) {
        contador++;
      }
    }

System.out.println("El total de 0´s es" + contador);
```

O, en su defecto, que es lo que yo haría, sería, simplemente, comprobar si el valor del entero recibido por consola dentro del for (y te ahorras de iteraciones y demás).

```
//Mantenemos el mismo valor de las variables de antes
int n = 0,c = 0,s = 0,contador = 0;

// Hacemos el bucle for y lo comprobamos ahí
for(c = 1;c <= s;c++) {
      System.out.println("Ingresa el numero" + c);
// Almacenamos el número de consola en el integer n
      n = entrada.nextInt();
// Y comprobamos aquí si es == 0. Si lo es, aumenta el contador en 1 más. Si no, pasa a la siguiente iteración.
      if(n == 0) {
        contador++;
      }
    }
```

Como puedes ver, te he cambiado el if de <= a ==, ya que lo que buscas es el número de 0, no los menores e iguales a 0.